# Alternate solution to reversing a string

Tags: string, algorithm

A common solution to this problem is to just start at the end of the string and copy all of the letters in reverse order to a new string then switch around the letters in each word of the new string to get the solution.

Why not do this:
Just create substrings of each word starting from the last word and add them to the end of the new string.

Answer (score 4):

You either misremembered the question or the interviewer screwed it up when he was asking you. The key part of this question is that the reversal must be done *in place*, that is, without using any storage other than that which is already holding the string.

The canonical answer about reversing the whole text, then re-reversing each word works in-place, while using substrings requires extra memory.